# Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this question.
Originally part of a mechanics question concerning a trains's motion.

I'm finding the time taken for a train to go from $75\textrm{km/hr}$ to $175\textrm{km/hr}$

The train weighs $300T$,
$\textrm{Tractive Effort}= C/v$ in $N$

$\textrm{Resistance} = 4750+kv^2$

Where $C= 2.60M$
and $k=13.3$

$T-R=ma$

$C/v-4750-kv^2=ma$

$C/(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}) -4750 -k(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt})^2 = m\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dx^2}$

I need to solve for $t$ from $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=75$ to $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=175$.
How do I solve for $t$?

Help appreciated!

Comment: So... what exactly do you expect from us? Just the answer? Or is this homework, and do you want a hint?

Comment: Method on how to proceed, If I can't solve it with the maths that I know, then I'll have to resort to a numerical method. It's not homework, just practice.

Comment: In that case, what are you trying to do (in terms of equations)?

Comment: Solve for time taken between v=75 and 175 km/hr

Comment: Well yes, that clearly is your question, but what approach are you trying, because I don't think this is very clear from what you wrote.

Comment: I'm assuming that I should integrate this twice?

Comment: Integrate *what* twice? Please clarify your question to get more useful comment and help.

Comment: Okay, I have a differential equation in the form: C/(dx/dt) -4750 -k(dx/dt)^2 = m(d^2x/dt^2) and I need to solve for t from dx/dt =75 50 dx/dt=175. 
I don't know of any method to solve this.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question rather than try to explain it in comments.

Comment: And if you're editing anyway, use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Right, that's in latex format now. I'm not really sure on what else to add, I just want to solve for t.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the equation
$$
C/(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}) -a_0 -k(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt})^2 = m\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dx^2}.
$$
Just put $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and your equation is
$$
   \frac{C}{v}-a_0-kv^2=m\frac{dv}{dt}.
$$
This reduces to the implicit solution
$$
   t_1-t_0=\int_{v_0}^{v_1}\frac{mvdv}{C-a_0v-kv^3}.
$$
The integral can be approached numerically for your problem.